# validate textbox after checkbox has been checked C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to perform validation based on the check box selection. Given below image shows demo fields:

[image]

The web page contains two field for manually enter values (Name, Age).
While clicking on submit button,

- If the checkbox is checked, then I need to validate textbox1 only.
- If the checkbox is unchecked, then I need to validate textbox2 only.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to perform the above task. I need solution. As a begginer I am struggled to find solution. Do you have any sample code to perform the above operation. Please help me

Comment: Basically almost all code is written after * in your requirements :)

Comment: Actually you do not need C# fot this purpose. You may validate whatever you want on client side with jQuery.

Comment: I have used required field validator. But I didn;t get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to validate this client-side, you will need to write your own javascript code or use one of the many javascript libraries available.

If you are okay with validating this server-side, you can use the built-in `CustomValidator`.  Since you have two different Textboxes to validate, I would use one validator for each textbox so you can have two different error messages, but you could do it with just one `CustomValidator`.

Your markup would be something like:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="*" OnServerValidate="TextBox1_Validate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="*" OnServerValidate="TextBox2_Validate" />
```

Then, your server code would look something like:

```
protected void TextBox1_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }

     //TODO:  Perform some validation on TextBox1 since the checkbox is checked.
}

protected void TextBox2_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }

    //TODO:  Perform some validation on TextBox2 since the checkbox is not checked.
}
```

You can get the value of the respective TextBox using `args.Value` if you use the CustomValidator per TextBox approach I'm suggesting.

Comment: I want to check the text box while clicking the submit buton. So what are the modification I have to do on the above solution. Let me know.

Comment: Can you clarify?  If you have the validators on the same Page or Control as the Submit button, they should automatically validate.  Another option is to specify a ValidationGroup so on both the validators and the Submit button and, so long as they match, the Submit button will automatically cause the validation.  You will need to add a check for if (Page.IsValid) within your submitButton_Click event to ensure the submit functionality doesn't run unless the validators return valid.